# Manhattan 5Lb, Ratios, Question 34

Tags: linear-algebra, ratio

Dick takes twice as long as Jane to run any given distance. Starting at the same moment, Dick and Jane run towards each other from opposite ends of the schoolyard, a total distance of x, at their respective constant rates until they meet.

Compare Quantity A and Quantity B

- Quantity A = The fraction of the total distance x that is covered by Jane
- Quantity B = 2x/3

According to me Quantity A = 2/3. => A and B cannot be compared because:

1) when x<1 => A is greater

2) when x=1 => A = B

3) when x>1 => B is greater

However as per the answer key: A = B.

Edit: [image: Image of the question]

Comment: Does the answer really depend on the length of the schoolyard? It doesn't.

Comment: Yes, and that's why I'm confused why the answer key says so.

Answer (score 1):

For any length of time, Jane will always run twice as far as Dick. However, their distances combined is always $x$. We can set up a system of equations for $D$, the distance Dick runs, and $J$, the distance Jane runs.
$$D+J=x$$
$$D=\frac{J}{2}$$
Thus 
$$J+\frac{J}{2}=x$$
Therefore $J=\frac{2x}{3}$.

Comment: The question asks for the fraction or part of the distance x covered by J. Shouldn't that be (2x/3) / x = 2/3 and not 2x/3?

Comment: @Ok, so $\frac{2x/3}{x}=\frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: Yes! That's why I am confused. Maybe the answer key is incorrect?

Comment: No, the answer key is probably right, but I think you may have copied it down wrong. Would you mind editing your post to include a picture of the problem of possible?

Comment: I've included an image, take a look.

Comment: In that case you are correct. But it's clearly a misprint.

Comment: Yes, so you may want to edit the answer accordingly and I'll mark it as 'accepted'. :)